# Update a table, by using value from a different table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Table STOCK**

```
INSERT INTO stock(stock_id, supplier_id, book_title, book_author, book_isbn, book_genre, stock_amount)  
VALUES(01,1101, 'Harry Potter', 'J.K.Rowling', '44-5678-234-8767', 'Young Adult', ***3***);
```

Above I have inserted data into my table, where there is only 3 books left.

**Table ORDERS**

```
INSERT INTO orders(order_num, emp_id, stock_id, supplier_id, supplier_name, book_title, book_author, order_date, order_amount, customer_contact, received)  
VALUES (1001 ,101 ,01 ,1101, 'Pengiun Books', 'Harry Potter', 'J.K. Rowling', '1-Mar-2017', ***10***, 0891234568,'***Y***');
```

Above 7 books were ordered and received.  Thus, they need to be added to stock.
Can anyone help me add the ordered amount to the amount in stock?

I'm using oracle-sqldeveloper

I've tried using the following, but it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE stock   
    SET stock.stock_amount = stock_amount + orders.order_amount  
    WHERE stock.stock_id = orders.stock_id;
```

Comment: Looking at the whole project you are trying to do you could maybe also use a after update trigger to update a value in another table.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can do this using `merge`.  Alternatively, you can use subqueries with `update`:

```
UPDATE stock s  
    SET stock_amount = s.stock_amount +
                       (SELECT sum(o.order_amount) 
                        FROM orders o
                        WHERE s.stock_id = o.stock_id
                       )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM orders o
                  WHERE s.stock_id = o.stock_id
                 );
```

Comment: @JenniferBester Please mark it as solution if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the solution in t-sql. Maybe it can help you.

```
UPDATE s
   SET stock_amount = stock_amount + o.order_amount  
FROM stock s
   INNER JOIN orders o ON o.stock_id = s.stock_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try a trigger that will automatically insert into stock as the 'received' column gets populated.
or simply use the join with update or merge statements to do the task.

Hope it helps!!